# Parse through XML childs

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

i have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Products>
 <Product>
  <name>Milk</name>
  <price>1.4</price>
  <productinfos>
   <category1 value="somecategory1"/>
   <category2 value="somecategory2"/>
   <category3 value="somecategory3"/>
  </productinfos>
 </Product>
</Products>
```

**how can i make sure that productinfos category1, category2 or category3 do exist and are not an empty string?** And how does the loop look like if i want the following output:

```
//output
Cat1: somecategory1
Cat3: somecategory3
Cat2: somecategory2
```

because sometimes the xml i parse looks different:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Products>
 <Product>
  <name>Milk</name>
  <price>1.4</price>
  <productinfos>
   <category1 value=""/>
   <category3 value="somecategory"/>
  </productinfos>
 </Product>
</Products>
```

in the above example, **how can i check if category2 exists?**

tia for your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `SimpleXMLElement::children()` method.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <name>Milk</name>
        <price>1.4</price>
        <productinfos>
            <category1 value="somecategory1"/>
            <category2 value="somecategory2"/>
            <category3 value="somecategory3"/>
        </productinfos>
    </Product>
</Products>
XML
);

// $xml is a SimpleXMLElement of <Products>
foreach ($xml->children() as $product) {
    if ($product->getName() != 'Product') {
        // ignore <Products><Cow> or whatever, if you care
        continue;
    }

    // start out assuming that everything is missing
    $missing_tags = array(
        'category1' => true,
        'category2' => true,
        'category3' => true,
    );

    // iterate through child tags of <productinfos>
    foreach ($product->productinfos->children() as $productinfo) {
        // element name is accessed using the getName() method, and
        // XML attributes can be accessed like an array
        if (isset($missing_tags[$productinfo->getName()]) &&
                !empty($productinfo['value'])) {
            $missing_tags[$productinfo->getName()] = false;
            echo $productinfo->getName() . ": " . $productinfo['value'] . "\n";
        }
    }

    // array_filter with one argument filters out any values that eval to false
    if (array_filter($missing_tags)) {
        echo "Missing tags: " . implode(", ", array_keys($missing_tags)) . "\n";
    }
}
```

The SimpleXML extension is rather less intuitive than the name would suggest, but it's about as simple as you can get with XML...